# Kubernetespodoperator how to use cmds or cmds and arguments to run multiple commands

Tags: python, kubernetes, airflow, google-cloud-composer

I'm using GCP composer to run an algorithm and at the end of the stream I want to run a task that will perform several operations copying and deleting files and folders from a volume to a bucket I'm trying to perform these copying and deleting operations via a `kubernetespodoperator`. I'm having hardship finding the right way to run several commands using "cmds" I also tried using "cmds" with "arguments".
Here is my `KubernetesPodOperator` and the cmds and arguments combinations I tried:

```
post_algo_run = kubernetes_pod_operator.KubernetesPodOperator(
    task_id="multi-coher-post-operations",
    name="multi-coher-post-operations",
    namespace="default",
    image="google/cloud-sdk:alpine",
    
    ### doesn't work ###
    cmds=["gsutil", "cp", "/data/splitter-output\*.csv",  "gs://my_bucket/data" , "&" , "gsutil", "rm", "-r", "/input"], 
    #Error:
        #[2022-01-27 09:31:38,407] {pod_manager.py:197} INFO - CommandException: Destination URL must name a directory, bucket, or bucket
        #[2022-01-27 09:31:38,408] {pod_manager.py:197} INFO - subdirectory for the multiple source form of the cp command.
    ####################

    ### doesn't work ###
    # cmds=["gsutil", "cp", "/data/splitter-output\*.csv",  "gs://my_bucket/data ;","gsutil", "rm", "-r", "/input"],
        # [2022-01-27 09:34:06,865] {pod_manager.py:197} INFO - CommandException: Destination URL must name a directory, bucket, or bucket
        # [2022-01-27 09:34:06,866] {pod_manager.py:197} INFO - subdirectory for the multiple source form of the cp command.
    ####################

    ### only preform the first command - only copying ###
    # cmds=["bash", "-cx"],
    # arguments=["gsutil cp /data/splitter-output\*.csv gs://my_bucket/data","gsutil rm -r /input"],                                    
        # [2022-01-27 09:36:09,164] {pod_manager.py:197} INFO - + gsutil cp '/data/splitter-output*.csv' gs://my_bucket/data
        # [2022-01-27 09:36:11,200] {pod_manager.py:197} INFO - Copying file:///data/splitter-output\Coherence Results-26-Jan-2022-1025Part1.csv [Content-Type=text/csv]...
        # [2022-01-27 09:36:11,300] {pod_manager.py:197} INFO - / [0 files][    0.0 B/ 93.0 KiB]                                                
        # / [1 files][ 93.0 KiB/ 93.0 KiB]
        # [2022-01-27 09:36:11,302] {pod_manager.py:197} INFO - Operation completed over 1 objects/93.0 KiB.
        # [20   22-01-27 09:36:12,317] {kubernetes_pod.py:459} INFO - Deleting pod: multi-coher-post-operations.d66b4c91c9024bd289171c4d3ce35fdd
    ####################


    volumes=[
        Volume(
            name="nfs-pvc",
            configs={
                "persistentVolumeClaim": {"claimName": "nfs-pvc"}
            },
        )
    ],
    volume_mounts=[
        VolumeMount(
            name="nfs-pvc",
            mount_path="/data/",
            sub_path=None,
            read_only=False,
        )
    ],
)
```

Comment: `cmds` behaves as [the entrypoint of the container](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/0ac3b8c3dd749c59e60cf0169580b9e7c5049d9e/airflow/providers/cncf/kubernetes/operators/kubernetes_pod.py#L89), if you dig inside the operator code you will find that it works as docker [ENTRYPOINT](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/python/blob/dac1f7bce7ca72cb4820ba96070450fb769f64f9/kubernetes/client/models/v1_container.py#L183) did you tested your entrypoint in a test docker image, first?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found a technic for running multiple commands.
First I found the relations between Kubernetespodoperator cmds and arguments properties to Docker's ENTRYPOINT and CMD.

Kubernetespodoperator cmds overwrite the docker original ENTRYPOINT
and Kubernetespodoperator arguments is equivalent to docker's CMD.

And so in order to run multiple commands from the Kubernetespodoperator I've used the following syntax:
I've set the Kubernetespodoperator cmds to run bash with -c:

```
cmds=["/bin/bash", "-c"],
```

And I've set the Kubernetespodoperator arguments to run two echo commands separated by &:

```
arguments=["echo hello && echo goodbye"],
```

So my Kubernetespodoperator looks like so:

```
stajoverflow_test = KubernetesPodOperator(
    task_id="stajoverflow_test",
    name="stajoverflow_test",
    namespace="default",
    image="google/cloud-sdk:alpine",
    cmds=["/bin/bash", "-c"],
    arguments=["echo hello && echo goodbye"],
)
```

Answer (score 1):

For your first command you need to make sure that inside your docker you are able to reach the working directory that will allows you to find file `/data/splitter-output\*.csv`

> ["gsutil", "cp", "/data/splitter-output*.csv",  "gs://my_bucket/data"]

You can test your commands on your docker image by using docker `RUN` so you can verify if you are providing correctly the commands.

On your second statement if you are making reference to a path inside your docker image again use `run` to test it. If you are referring to google storage you have to provide the full path.

> ["gsutil", "rm", "-r", "/input"]

Its worth to mention that `ENTRYPOINT` will run once container starts running as described on [understand how cmd and entrypoint interact](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#understand-how-cmd-and-entrypoint-interact). As mention in the comment, if you look at the [code](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/python/blob/dac1f7bce7ca72cb4820ba96070450fb769f64f9/kubernetes/client/models/v1_container.py#L183) `cmds` it replaces docker image `ENTRYPOINT`.
It also recommends to follow the guidelines of [Define a Command and Arguments for a Container](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/inject-data-application/define-command-argument-container/)

Comment: Many thanks! My core issue is how can I run more than one command, even simply two echo commands.

Comment: In the same line you can add `&&` to your statement as show on [entrypoint](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#:~:text=form%20ENTRYPOINT%20example-,%F0%9F%94%97,-You%20can%20use) example (which uses a `run` cmd ).